# Como hago para que el código funcione bien

Tags: python

Quiero unir dos letras con una lista vacía, pero la letras se separan antes de estar unida

Ejemplo: join(lista) une la primera letra digamos "L" y después la segunda letras "A", y después las otras letras de la lista y se tiene que unir para formar LAUTY digamos pero sale así ["L","A","U","T","Y"] lo quiero unido no separado en una lista

```
from pynput import keyboard 
import time

lista = []

o = 0

while o <= 5:
    
    def pulsa(tecla):
        lista.append(tecla)

        lis = "".join(str(lista))
        print(lis)
 



    def suelta(tecla):
        if tecla == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('ctrl'):
            return False

    keyboard.Listener(pulsa, suelta).run()

    o+=1
```

Comment: Quita el str del str(lista). Str convierte la lista en una cadena

Comment: Un consejo para que tu código sea menos confuso: llama a las variables "numero" por algo más acertado como "letra", así, si vos o alguien más lee el código, le será más facil entender que se tratan de letras y no de números. Del mismo modo, en este caso no es tan importante, pero debido a lo anterior, no suele ser recomendable que las variables consistan en una sola letra